# How to integrate own tile server on top of MapQuest?

Tags: java, android, mapquest

I need to replace MapQuest's map with my tile server URL which looks like **http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png** by keeping the controls as it is Eg: Marker & Polygon. I followed this [link](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/android-sdk/) and couldn't find a source to my problem.

The below image is my present mapview which is generated by MapQuest

[image: current MapQuest map] How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The MapQuest mapping tools are built to display MapQuest maps. There is no method to display other maps. You may want to try osmdroid.

Comment: Is it possible to include my custom tile server through osmdroid seperately and add the mapquest's map controls on top of it?

Comment: MapQuest's controls are built for our sdk. But you could recreate the basic functionality on the osmdroid map.

Comment: I tried by following this link https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid and managed to put my tileserver, polyline & marker but couldn't find any help with integrating polygon, marker snippet & click listeners. Even their source code extends with several classes (looks complicated) and i was unable to fetch the code for each controls clearly.

Comment: I haven't used osmdroid, but this may help with the polygon: http://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocAll/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/Polygon.html